# How do I enable multiple-users and FDE in Ubuntu-touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm not particularly concerned about the problem since it's still in alpha/beta, but the [project site](http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet) notes the feature.

I went ahead and bought a Nexus 7 to be on the early adopter platform, so I'm just wondering if this is something that is "coming before stable" or if I'm missing some configuration step that should maybe be on the project wiki.